# Mathematical Proof : Is a binary tree a BST?

Tags: induction, computer-science, recursion, trees

Could anyone familliarize me with the proper way to approach a mathematical proof (Induction \ Recursion) regarding BST?

BST = Binary Search tree, where each node is: Greater than all of the values in his left subtree, Smaller than all the values in his right subtree. And each subtree in a BST is also a BST.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Verification

I know how to do it in code but would like to write it as a proof.

I guess the base case for the induction\ recursion would be the same:

Range of the current root's value:  x in(-inf,+inf)
Range of the next left root: y in (-inf,x)
Range of the next right root: z in (x,+inf)

But what is the PROPER way to Prove that it actually produces a BST Tree check?

EDIT:
Summary of what I currently pursued:

Induction on N : number of nodes which aren't leaves in a BST
Assuming: (Min,Max) : Range of node X
Base case: 
N = 0 ->  Empty BST Tree
               OR
          BST Tree with only one node X : X is in (-inf,+inf)
N = 1 ->  BST Tree with one node which is not a leaf: X in (-inf,+inf)
          BST -> Left 'son' Y : Y < X -> Y in (-inf,x)
          BST -> Right 'son' Z: Z > X -> Z in (x,+inf)
          (If either or both sons exist)

Induction: Assuming BST with N nodes which aren't leaves X =  {X1,X2....XN}
For all x in X : x in (min,max) -> y in (min,x) and z in (x,max)

Induction step: Taking a N + 1 nodes which aren't leaves BST:
(Now what I'm conteplating about):
Removing one node which has up to two descendats (At height H - 1)

Therefore two possible options:

1). Now it's a BST with N Nodes which arent leaves -> Induction assumption proves the verification works -> Adding it back and it still works
2). Now it's a BST with N - 1 Nodes which arent leaves (Because the node we removed was it's parent's only son, so we removed 2 of such nodes)

---That's where I'm stuck, I don't know the proper way to write it from this point.. Maybe regarding that Xn+1 and Xn which was Xn+1's parent? ----

Comment: What does BST mean here? Binary Search Tree?

Comment: Yes Sorry I will make it more clear thank you :)

Comment: I don't get why you are trying to inductively prove it. I also don't understand why you are not considering the leaves.